# Use OpenStreet Maps in my blackberry application

Tags: openstreetmap, blackberry-maps

I would like to use openstreet maps in my blackberry application. The idea is the application fetches the current location through GPS/cell tower. The user has an option to click on a button and load the map within the application (same display) below. I have researched a little and BlackBerry maps seem to be limited and Google Maps requires installing a seperate API. I am hoping to fetch and load the maps through http connection (something like a webservice). Can somebody please guide?

Comment: Guys, can anyone please help. I am unable to sort this one out.

Answer (score 0):

I use the nutiteq library its usefull and it implements the openstreet maps in my blackberry. Here are some links quick start [nutiteq RIM BlackBerry Mapping API SDK](http://www.nutiteq.com/rim-blackberry-mapping-api-sdk)